# Time Auto-correlation function for a polar reutrn-to-zero waveform

Tags: communication, signal-processing, digital-communications, matlab, random

I used matlab to calculate the time Auto-correlation function for a polar return-to-zero waveform
to make sure that it has an ergodic property . I implemented the following formula as a function in matlab 
[image: Time ACF]

I then got the following output Rxx(m) plotted versus the time shift (m or lags).
I expected the output to be A^2 at n=0 according to analysis of polar RZ data shown here in page #10:
https://homepages.wmich.edu/~bazuinb/ECE3800CMcG/Notes7_2.pdf

but in matlab it showed me the following output (with Rxx(m) = A^2/2 = 8 ).
Notice that the vector has 100 bits ,each bit is sampled 8 times(Tb=8ms) , that is 1x800 vector . I plotted it vs lags in ms but it may not be clear in the graph below . 
[image]

so Can anyone explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

The return-to-zero code spends half its time at zero volts, so half of the signal samples contribute nothing to the total of the autocorrelation integration. Therefore, if the pulse amplitude is ±A, then the autocorrelation peak will be \$\frac{A^2}{2}\$.

Page 10 in that paper is talking about the power spectral density, which is a different measure from the autocorrelation function.

Comment: okey but for the ensemble auto-correlation (which I will use to get the PSD in my analysis) shows almost the same graph ! however, when I calculate it I found it 
Rx(tau) = A^2(1-2|tau|/Tb) which gives A^2 at tau = 0 (tau is the lag) . although in MATLAB , it's A^2/2 too . So , Am I calculating the ensemble ACF incorrectly ?